# How to output a separate output file for each key in the reducer?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a map-reduce program in which the mappers generate multiple keys. According to the map-reduce framework all pairs having the same key are transferred to the same reducer. Let's say I have 10 keys (in total) and 3 reducers. What the reducers output at the end is 3 output files. Is there any technique to generate a separate output file for each key and output 10 output file at the end? It is possible to have 10 reducers, but when the number of keys increases this solution may not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't sound like a very good idea. You'll face severe issues once you start using Hadoop for **real stuff**.

But if you still need it, why don't you skip the Reduce phase. Just emit the output directly from Mappers followed by a Combiner.

Comment: The idea of skipping the Reduce phase is great. But how I can write the output of the mapper to a file?

Comment: You don't have to do anything. It works similar to the case when Reducers are used. Just set the number of reducers to zero.

Comment: I actually set the number of reducers to zero, but I got only one output file at the end. Any idea?

Comment: Because your data is so small that generating multiple mappers to process it would be an overkill.

Comment: Can you explain why it may not be efficient if each file has size 64MB (assuming the hadoop block size is 64MB too)

Comment: If the files are very small(smaller than HDFS block) then the the cost of creating multiple mappers for each key/value pair would be more than processing all the records of that file by a single mapper.

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with using the old `mapred` API then there is an alternative to do this:

You may go for an overridden extension of `MultipleTextOutputFormat` and then make all the contents of the record to be the part of 'value', while make the file-name or path to be the key.

There is already an implementation provided in the [oddjob](https://github.com/jblomo/oddjob) library : `MultipleLeafValueOutputFormat`, you can implement yourself too.

Read more about it [here](http://www.infoq.com/articles/HadoopOutputFormat). Also read my similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18998603/610305).